# Third party script wont load until page refresh

Tags: javascript, gatsby, netlify, addthis

I run into a problem with my blog that I've been writing content for months now. I'm using Gatsby v2 and the Netlify CMS v2 and host the entire blog with the help of Netlify and Github.

I've asked for help a few days ago but the thread got deleted due to not enough clarification.

So, I'm trying again now.

I'm using this starter: https://github.com/thriveweb/yellowcake , and haven't changed much besides CSS yet.

I'm trying to improve my blog by updating the /src/templates/SinglePost.js template for all my blog posts by adding share buttons from Addthis.com. I've successfully added their code (script) to my blog:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-545927b3c48573a"></script>
```

by using Netlifys Snippet injection option. This option allows to inject analytics or other scripts into the HTML of the site before `</body>` tag.

but since its a static website, If I enter the website from the home URL it doesn't load the script on other pages. I have to refresh (reload) the blog post in order to see the share buttons if I'm coming from the homepage or any other page from the website. Is there a way to refresh the blog posts automatically when a user enters the blog post when he's coming from the homepage?

Looking for solutions :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59574000/how-to-refresh-addthis-in-react

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
<body onload="addScript()">

function addScript() { 
   var my_script = document.createElement('script'); 
   my_script.setAttribute('src','http.....'); 
   document.head.appendChild(my_script); 
}
```

Comment: What's that suppose to do @Qhori